# Without Clear browser cache get the new images and new updated CSS

Tags: css, caching, browser-cache

I am having the Website "website.com",i updated the design(CSS) and images   day by day.if any of the new guest user open this "website.com" it will   load the updated design as good.

But i am not a new guest user,i already viewed this "website.com" page   in my system as many times,but the updated images and Design changes(CSS)   not get updated to my browser,it only show the old design and some times   it show the collapse with old and new design.

There have any way to get the updated design in my browser with out   manually clear the browser cache.

Thank in advance.

Comment: can you specify more? working with PHP? HTML? You have backend access? you are re-uploading the entire website?

Comment: only HTML,CSS and images

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid that on client side you can add something like `?v=1.x` to CSS file link, when the file content is changed. For example, if there was `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">` you can change it to `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?v=1.1">`. I think, with images the same situation, I'm don't sure.